# Magento crash when I save or apply Catalog Price Rule

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a very rare error for some days. The server goes down because the httpd in the server is increasing second by second GB... in minutes is in more than 20gb.
The service httpd has to be restarted and next other time the same.
We have ask to the server company, and says that there is a "query" that its all the time generating and its done infinitely:

> sendto(39, "\316\1\0\0\3SELECT catalog_product_entity_tier_price.value_id AS price_id, catalog_product_entity_tier_price.website_id, catalog_product_entity_tier_price.`all_group
>   poll([{fd=39, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=39, revents=POLLIN}])
>   recvfrom(39, "\1\0\0\1\6y\0\0\2\3def\21DATABASE_NAME!catalog_product_entity_tier_price!catalog_product_entity_tier_price\10price_id\10value_id\f?\0\v\0\0\0\3\3B\0\0\0}\0\0\3\3def\21espa

We don't know what to do, we have test a lot of things and nothing.

> UPDATE: We have seen that this "crash" happens when I apply or save a
>   "Catalog Price Rule"

Comment: How much Catalog Price Rule exits at  your system,?

Comment: Also, check boot actively happen on your website.I strongly recommend implementing web firewall for your website. Also, Update to Magento security patch

Comment: Hello, only a few, 5.
I have firewall in the server... it´s a very rare problem :S

Comment: Hello, I think that its not the catalog price rule as other time crashed...
The httpd in server increases to more than 30GN in minutes

Comment: Have you checked Cron list & most important web firewall like sucuri.I have face boot track, and  it is prevented by Webfirewall